# Espresso test scroll behaviour on RecyclerView not working in Emulator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I've got the follow espresso code to scroll to a listitem inside a RecyclerView:

```
onView(withId(R.id.selectionTrainingList))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .perform(scrollToHolder(matcher), actionOnHolderItem(matcher, click()))
```

Where `R.id.selectionTrainingList` is the RecyclerView.
This code works well if I run it on a real device, but if I run this on an emulator it won't scroll down.

Is there any solution to make this work on an emulator?

Comment: Just test it in a phyisical device, there's simply things that doesn't work on emulator, and always is better to test every app in physical devices

Answer (score 0):

According to [ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#isDisplayed()), it seems that `.check(matches(isDisplayed()))` can fail if your `RecyclerView` becomes too *tall* to be displayed on screen, so try without the check:

```
onView(withId(R.id.selectionTrainingList)).perform(actionOnHolderItem(matcher, click()))
```

You can also drop the `scrollToHolder` action because `actionOnHolderItem` does it too.